# Как сделать так, чтобы исходный url не менялся при использовании Pjax?

Tags: pjax

```
<?php
    Pjax::begin([]);
    $typeForm = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['/post/add-type2'],
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'addType',
            'data' => ['pjax' => true],
        ]
    ]);
    // данные формы и закрытие формы и pjax-а
?>
```

в обработчике есть:

```
// логика обработчика
return $this->render('multiple',compact('types'));
```

Все работает как надо, данные записываются и выводятся, только 1 момент. Как заставить PJax, не изменять текущий url? На выходе получаю.../post/add-type2, т.е. содержимое параметра action, а надо чтобы оно не менялось. Обработчик сработал ну и хорошо, а изменение ссылки не нужно. Как сделать такую вещь?

Answer (score 2):

решение найдено, надо было просто добавить 1 параметр:

```
Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]);
```